Win 11 IOT application no comms when running as a service
I have an application built in C# that sends a message over UDP to a PLC. Based on the content of that message, the PLC fires a UDP message back with necessary information. The app works fine in VS debug mode. The app works fine if I use the executable. The app was originally designed in VS as a service and works on several other deployments Win 10, server, etc. without issue. I don't believe we have used it on Win 11 IOT.
I registered the same functioning executable in powershell with sc.exe create "Service Name: binpath= "the actual path to the executable". I then run it from the services tab.
When monitoring from the PC it appears Windows is suspending the service. Everything I find indicates this could be related to power settings, so I changed the power settings to performance mode. When in performance mode, the app runs in efficiency mode. Occasionally it doesn't appear to suspend or run in efficiency mode. Regardless it appears to hang. This is all I can really do from the power settings tab. They seem to have removed every useful feature for tuning app performance.
When monitoring from the PLC side, I have counters that increment when UDP messages are received. These counters aren't incrementing. This leads me to believe the process is hanging up, or Windows is hanging it up.
Firewall is disabled completely for the moment as part of troubleshooting, so I don't think it is the culprit.
Checked allow the service to interact with the desktop - No change.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Found the issue was actually with a different part of the program. I was storing the received message in an SQL database. Running the application as local wasn't giving me the proper credentials to access SQL.
To fix, in the Services window, right clicked on the service, selected properties. Log On tab was set to Local System Account. I had to select "This Account" and input the details of my user account.
Service appears to be running now.
